# C Import issue Node Rs232

Tags: c, node.js, serial-port

I have the following structure:

```
~/Desktop/hellonode$ ls 
build    rs232.h    testnode.js    helloworld.cc    helloworld.node    rs232.c
```

and in `rs232.h`:

```
int OpenComport(int, int);
```

But when I try to create a node native plugin and use the following code:

```
#include "rs232.h"

using namespace v8;

void init(Handle<Object> target) {
  int cport_nr=0;        /* /dev/ttyS0 (COM1 on windows) */

  if(OpenComport(cport_nr, bdrate))
  {
    printf("Can not open comport\n");
    return;
  }

  target->Set(String::NewSymbol("hello"),
      FunctionTemplate::New(Method)->GetFunction());
}
```

I build the plugin using 
    node-waf

Everything compiles fine, however, when I try running it I get the following error:

> `~/Desktop/hellonode$ node testnode`
>   `node: symbol lookup error: <~>/Desktop/hellonode/build/Release/helloworld.node: undefined symbol: OpenComport`

Comment: Please post the command you use to build the executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a link error, not a compiler error.  Is `OpenComport` defined in `rs232.c`, and are you linking `rs232.c` into your executable?

Comment: Hummm I think you might be on to something I will look into how to add the link using node-waf (the node compiler)

Comment: To expand a bit, you would change the following line in your wscript file... obj.source = "helloworld.cc">obj.source = "helloworld.cc rs232.C". One important note here, without changes to configuration node requires a capital C extension for C files. I handled this by using a symlink.